# Change special inline code styling to block code styling in Markdown

Tags: github, awk, sed, markdown

I am using a unique style for demonstrating code in a tutorial written in Markdown.

With GitHub's new "Copy" button in code blocks (as of May '21), I want to change all my inline commands to block `console` code, thereby making my tutorials easier for students.

(You are welcome to see the actual tutorials if you want: [VIP Linux](https://github.com/inkVerb/VIP/))

## My problem

Where `34` could be any numbers, letters, or Hyphen

And the comment may or may not exist

And all files end with `.md`

I want to change this:

```
| **34** :$ `one cli command here` Optional `code` comment, *maybe* with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>
```

...to this:

````
| **34** :$ Optional `code` comment, *maybe* with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>

```console
one cli command here
```
````

---

## My research

I can use `sed` easily for part of this operation

````
sed 's/** :$ `/** :$\n```console\n/' *.md | sed 's:` :\n```\n\n:'
````

Changing:

```
| **10** :$ `some command` Some `code` *comment*
```

...to:

````
| **10** :$    
```console
some command
```

Some `code` *comment*
````

But, I need `Some code *comment*` to remain on the same line as `| **10** :$`

---

## Why I'm asking

This may be a job for `awk`. Even if I understood `awk`, the necessary regex eludes me.

I may use text place holders in the final `sed` statement, then `grep` to change `Optional code *comments*` manually. But, I'd rather contribute to the community with a question, which could also save me time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use capture groups and backreferences:

````sh
$ cat ip.txt
| **10** :$ `some command` Some `code` *comment*

$ sed -E 's/(\*\* :\$) `([^`]+)`(.*)/\1\3\n\n```console\n\2\n```/' ip.txt
| **10** :$ Some `code` *comment*

```console
some command
```
````

`(regexp)` will capture the portion matched which you can recall later by using `\1`, `\2`, etc. The leftmost `(` gets group number `1`, next leftmost `(` gets number `2` and so on.

Comment: That works as a drop-in code, no changes needed. IMHO it's the "proper" way. `awk` may be a sledgehammer, but `awk` solutions still welcome.

Comment: I wouldn't use `awk` for this problem since I can't see an easy way to manipulate fields (particularly because of backtick usage after the code to be captured). If you want to use substitution features, you'd need `gawk` for backreference (with a more verbose syntax compared to `sed`) and workaround for non-gawk solution would be tedious. See also [When to use grep, less, awk, sed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/303044/when-to-use-grep-less-awk-sed)

Comment: awk has no concerns about backticks.

Comment: @EdMorton I meant in terms of field manipulation, if there were only two backticks in the line, it would be easy to know how many fields will be there

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for gensub():

````
$ awk '{$0=gensub(/([^`]*)`([^`]*)` (.*)/,"\\1\\3\n\n```console\n\\2\n```",1)} 1' file
| **34** :$ Optional `code` comment, *maybe* with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>

```console
one cli command here
```
````

or with GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():

````
$ awk 'match($0,/([^`]*)`([^`]*)` (.*)/,a){$0=a[1] a[3] "\n\n```console\n" a[2] "\n```"} 1' file
| **34** :$ Optional `code` comment, *maybe* with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>

```console
one cli command here
```
````

or with any awk:

````
$ awk 'match($0,/`[^`]*`/){$0=substr($0,1,RSTART-1) substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH+1) "\n\n```console\n" substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2) "\n```"} 1' file
| **34** :$ Optional `code` comment, *maybe* with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>

```console
one cli command here
```
````